# Substituting variable value in AWS CLI DynamoDB Query Operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am writing a shell script to query an attribute from dynamoDB table. I am using AWS CLI to write the script.

I want to find AccountId from MY_TABLE_NAME for ReferenceId gfsdgrhfsh. When I supply the exact value of the attribute in the AttributeValueList, the query operation succeeds and I get the correct attribute value.

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME \
  --select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES --attributes-to-get "AccountId" \
  --key-conditions '{"ReferenceId": {"AttributeValueList": [ {"S": "gfsdgrhfsh" } ], "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"} }' \
  --limit 1 | jq '.Items[0].AccountId.S'
```

The above command gives me the correct account id.

However, when I am assigning the ReferenceId gfsdgrhfsh to a variable and then putting this variable in the command, I am not getting a response.

`referenceId=gfsdgrhfsh`

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME \
  --select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES --attributes-to-get "AccountId" \
  --key-conditions '{"ReferenceId": {"AttributeValueList": [ {"S": "$referenceId" } ], "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"} }' \
  --limit 1 | jq '.Items[0].AccountId.S'
```

Can someone please advise on how to inject the value of the variable in the command. I have to perform query operation for lots of referenceIds by reading them from a file, so I need to inject the variable value in the command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured out, we need to pass the value enclosed within double quotes. The below command works :

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME \
  --select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES --attributes-to-get "AccountId" \
  --key-conditions '{"ReferenceId": {"AttributeValueList": [ {"S": '\"$referenceId\"' } ], "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"} }' \
  --limit 1 | jq '.Items[0].AccountId.S'
```